# Different brand, slightly bigger than Lego

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I have a set of Technic bricks used by an academy for teaching robotics to children.

They are not compatible with Lego (I think that the pitch is 9mm instead of the 8.6mm of the original Lego design).

I would like to buy additional components, so I wonder if there is any known brand or shop that sell these type of bricks (including Chinese manufacturers or AliExpress stores, for example).

Edit: added image. At some components I can read HND##, but searching for HND I only find Haneda airport in Japan [image]

Comment: Welcome to Brick.SE. Could you please add a picture of the elements you have? I'm not familiar with clone brands, but having something visual might help others with identification of the brand.

Comment: Seconding the request, without either a brand name or a photo, it is going to be probably impossible to identify any stores that sell it. Are there any markings on the pieces, numbers or text, maybe just a logo? Even if not, a photo could help jog someone's memory.

Comment: (Note, I added the part-identification tag since the information OP is looking for fits the  "what kit a particular block is from" part of the tag description, but feel free to remove it if it rather should not be used in this case.)

Comment: If Rafael graces us with photos I hope they include some Technics or a good ruler in the photo so we can see the differences easier.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! I have added a picture and described the code that it's visible at some components (HND##). Additionally, this is the academy that uses these components: https://kids.athuman.com/robo/en/course/https://kids.athuman.com/robo/en/course/

Comment: I think the link is [https://kids.athuman.com/robo/en/course/](https://kids.athuman.com/robo/en/course/).

Answer (score 3):

Taking an image from the linked course site and using [Google Image Search for reverse image searching](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&hl=en-DE&tbs=sbi:AMhZZiv-rCnpKCtpRQXNZbpkRlTpATBuoVl6PEtuCg7bhXiHIo0jK-E3rGnJFPx6lmkB6GHekoagM-xf6xyZ6JEetcKg3v3pZJpi0F6ATF6f2j7vdlKxSMKM_1_1mBs8wrfDFgkO_1pbJ5MfFuAoLXFWc4m9MLEvtIfty6oPtcrlnpgRLjMV5xynpMHn0Qc_1JkGBU1_1ev1036T06cLMteTzGDKYuLINK0IZE68emBZb4Qeoe7WR9p-twDxknrNBsuWsXGmJyS2qqJqjMzu8K40fgo60yyglOyJC77UFTSEV-aQxBr17Ozlkc37_1wZQfCeLRcawHgszLwManwu2JoUXRHJaHf3WXJk-j6Q&sxsrf=ALeKk02RG51V-TnJxMdIEoJfBbVuo0gEhA:1608542692056&ei=5GngX5HeAo-ZkwWQnKLQAQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiR4I--4N7tAhWPzKQKHRCOCBoQ8NMDegQIEBBH&biw=1671&bih=942), then applying a layer of Google Translate to make sense of the exclusively Japanese results has convinced me that this type of building system is only used in this robotics course in Japan. Nonetheless, the institution [seems to sell the sets as standalone products](https://vi7mbg64th3oi34gocfi76g4nu--chiicomi-com.translate.goog/shop/623334/topics/623380/) for 28,500 yen, unless I misunderstand the translation results somehow:

> At Human Academy's Robot Class, we will increase the number of kits that will be added when advancing the course, based on the standard kit (* 1) that you purchase when you join.
>
> [...]
>
> (* 1) 28,500 yen 〚tax excluded〛

Comment: Yes, it is possible to buy extra components directly from them, but it is quite expensive, that is why I was looking for an alternative. Additionally, they do not have many components like differentials, pulleys or worm gears.
I think the best approach is to buy cheap lego clones from aliexpress and then make adaptors to fit with the rest of components.

Thank you very much for your help searching for the manufacturer, anyways
I have been checking more in detail and it seems that the scale is exactly 1.2 lego size

Comment: @Rafael You're most definitely welcome! Feel free to return and write an answer if you do find a distributor or manage to engineer adapter pieces :)